# Custom control collection - Adding items at design time?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a reusable control similar to an Outlook-style sidebar.  I have a CustomPanel.  I also have a CustomCollectionControl, that inherits from flow layout panel.  At design time I would like to add (x) CustomPanels to my CustomCollectionControl, through the properties window.

When I try to add from the (Collection) list in the properties window, it will show up in the list, but it will not add it to the control that is on the form.

Here is my code so far.

```
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class CustomCollectionControl

    Inherits FlowLayoutPanel

    ''' <summary> 
    ''' Required designer variable.
    ''' </summary>
    Private _mComponents As Container = Nothing

    Private _mCustompanels As CustomPanelCollection

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        _mCustompanels = New CustomPanelCollection(Me)

        Padding = New Padding(0)

    End Sub

#Region "Component Designer generated code"
    ''' <summary> 
    ''' Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    ''' the contents of this method with the code editor.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        _mComponents = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
    End Sub
#End Region

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)> _
    <Browsable(True)> _
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)> _
    <Bindable(True)> _
    Public Property CustomPanels() As CustomPanelCollection
        Get
            Return _mCustompanels
        End Get
        Set(value As CustomPanelCollection)
            _mCustompanels = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnResize(e As EventArgs)

        MyBase.OnResize(e)

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class CustomPanelCollection
    Inherits CollectionBase

    Private _mControl As CustomCollectionControl

    Private _mCustomCollectionControl As CustomCollectionControl

    Friend Sub New(control As CustomCollectionControl)

        _mCustomCollectionControl = control

    End Sub

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(index As Integer) As CustomPanel
        Get
            Return DirectCast(List(index), CustomPanel)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function Contains(cPanel As CustomPanel) As Boolean

        Return List.Contains(cPanel)

    End Function

    Public Function Add(cPanel As CustomPanel) As Integer

        Dim i As Integer

        i = List.Add(cPanel)
        cPanel.Control = _mCustomCollectionControl

        Return i

    End Function

    Public Sub Remove(cPanel As CustomPanel)

        List.Remove(cPanel)
        cPanel.Control = Nothing

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class CustomPanel
    Inherits Panel

    Friend Control As CustomCollectionControl

    Public Sub New()

        ' TODO Set Stuff!
        Height = 100
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Margin = New Padding(0)
        Padding = New Padding(0)

        Dim cBtn As New Button
        cBtn.Height = 30
        Controls.Add(cBtn)
        cBtn.Dock = DockStyle.Top

    End Sub

End Class
```

I need to find out when a CustomPanel is added through the properties window during design time, how to update the control with the changes?

Comment: You might consider a more minimal (ie much less complex) complete example.  I mostly follow what you are asking, but there seems to be "extra" UserControl things in the code from when it once inherited from UC.   It makes it hard to tell if these are causing problems are not without rewriting it to find out.  However, If I add a Panel thru the collection editor they are not added to the form/control (add from menu and via editor diont do the same thing). Panels are contained in 2 collections though: Controls and CustomPanels.

Comment: I have went in and updated my original post.  I have removed the button for now, so I am just trying to add the collection of CustomPanels to my CustomCollectionControl (flow layout panel).  The code block is down to 125 lines now.

IN a new project I can paste this into a new class and it works.  I can add/remove stuff to the (Collection) in the properties window, but those changes do not reflect on the actual control.

Comment: Is this thing supposed to *only* accept CustomPanels; and are CustomPanels *only* supposed to be used in the control?

Comment: Yes, only CustomPanels, which is just a generic panel.

Comment: The idea behind this is just to show a simple way to to display a list of controls in a container at design time.  Finding examples at run time is easy, but not at design time.

It would be nice to have the added ability to add through the control like I was doing, like how you can add tab pages to a tab control 2 ways, but ultimately I only need the add/remove reflected from the collection through properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that in order for the flow-layout logic to work on your panels, they need to be in the base control's ControlCollection.  If/When you expose this thru the properties IDE the standard collection editor allows any control to be added to it.

Your `CustomPanels()` property on the other hand, allows only `CustomPanel` controls but they get stored in a different collection, so they do not show up on the form.

The `SmartTag` action to only add `CustomPanel` is a very viable workaround if it adds to the `Controls` collection.  I am not sure how many of the standard `Panel` properties you want them to be able to edit, and since there is no way to specify the child button properties, there doesnt seem much difference between the collection editor and the `SmartTag`.  I assume this is because it is a work in progress and/or removed to post a minimal example.

Another way is to get rid if the extra collection and use a custom collection editor which will restrict the type of control to what you want.  This is shown below.

Notes:

- I changed the generic names to make it easier to read.  `CustomCollectionControl` is now `FlowLayoutPanelEx` and `CustomPanel` is `FlowPanel`.
- Your Buttons arent hooked up to anything, nor are they exposed, so I am not sure how you plan to use them.
- Since all that the `FlowPanel` does is store that one button, why not omit it and just add buttons of a certain size?
- There are several other issues with the code(e.g. `CustomPanel/FlowPanel` should implement `IDisposable` since it is creating stuff).  These and other issues are ignored in order to focus on implementing a minimal custom collection editor.

FlowLayoutPanelEx and FlowPanel:

```
' collection editor will need this:
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design

Public Class FlowLayoutPanelEx
    Inherits FlowLayoutPanel

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
        ' {PL} - no, it is not
        'InitializeComponent()

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        Padding = New Padding(0)
    End Sub

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
    Browsable(True),
   DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    Bindable(True),
    Editor(GetType(FlowPanelCollectionEditor),
           GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))>
    Public Overloads Property Controls() As ControlCollection
        Get
            Return MyBase.Controls
        End Get
        Set(value As ControlCollection)

        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class FlowPanel
    Inherits Panel
    ' ToDo: implememt IDisposable

    Private myBtn As Button

    ' allow user to specify the text for the child button 
    Public Property ButtonText As String
        Get
            If myBtn IsNot Nothing Then
                Return myBtn.Text
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            myBtn.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        ' TODO Set Stuff!
        Height = 100
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Margin = New Padding(0)
        Padding = New Padding(0)
        Height = 40

        myBtn = New Button
        myBtn.Height = 30
        Controls.Add(myBtn)
        myBtn.Dock = DockStyle.Top

    End Sub

End Class
```

The way you have it, the user can change any `FlowPanel` property in the Collection Editor including those you have explicitly set.  I dont know enough about what you ultimately want to do to offer alternatives other than it seems like perhaps the Panel is cosmetic and maybe a Button alone would suffice.

Note the additional `Editor` attribute on the `Controls` property.  This tells VS to use that collection editor:

```
Public Class FlowPanelCollectionEditor
    Inherits CollectionEditor

    Public Sub New(t As Type)
        MyBase.New(t)   
    End Sub

    ' *** Magic happens here: ***
    ' override the base class to SPECIFY the Type allowed
    ' rather than letting it derive the Types from the collection type
    ' which would allow any control to be added
    Protected Overrides Function CreateNewItemTypes() As Type()
        Dim ValidTypes As Type() = {GetType(FlowPanel)}
        Return ValidTypes

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function EditValue(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                        provider As IServiceProvider,
                                        value As Object) As Object
        Return MyBase.EditValue(context, provider, value)
    End Function

End Class
```

Results:

The collection editor adds only FlowPanels:

[image]

As you can see, the new `ButtonText` property can be set from the collection editor.  When the controls are added to the Controls collection for use on the form, `ButtonText` shows on the buttons:

[image] [image]

Note that the user can still drag a `TextBox` or whatever to your `FlowLayoutPanelEx` and it will accept it.  This is another of those "other issues" mentioned above.

---

An article on [CodeProject, Enhanced CollectionEditor Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718006/Enhanced-CollectionEditor-Framework) provides a fairly comprehensive overview of collections and custom collection editors.

It includes a custom collection editor framework but it wont handle this situation as is.  If you remove `NotOverridable` from the `CreateNewItemTypes` method and recompile, you should be able to inherit from `EnhancedCollectionEditor` and use some of the other features it provides.

It is not really needed; as the code above shows there is not much involved in restricting the Type allowed.  The article might be of value though as you modify and refine `FlowPanel` and the button into their final form. (Disclaimer: I wrote the article).

Comment: As I said in the original post I am trying to make an Outlook-styled sidebar.  More details: The main panel is supposed to contain a collection of panels, and each of those contain a button, rectangle, or whatever as a header.  When the header is clicked it will extend the panels' height.  The panel itself will act like a menu which is displayed when clicking the header.  When the full panel is displayed it will show whatever I have dropped in it (i.e. a few buttons, a list of objects, etc).  There is probably a much more logical solution, but it apparently is alluding me.

...cont

Comment: I am able to create this effect on the designer with a flow layout panel and a few regular panels with the buttons docked, but it is not something that I have had any success in making into a reusable control that I can just drop on the form.  I have not even put thought into restricting the types that can be put into the main control, nor worried with the IDisposable.  My goal was just to get the controls on there then worry about the rest...but you were able to do this in under 100 lines of code!

...cont

Comment: I really do not know how I did not come across your article either on CodeProject, because I went through dozens of articles on there that might point me in the right direction.

I will be taking a few hours tonight to go over your article.  I really appreciate you taking the time to work through this...it really has helped!

Comment: It *sounds like* maybe just a label center-top on the panel would suffice.  When the panel is clicked, expand it or contract it.  I'm not sure where the menu items come into play (I dont have Outlook), but that is a different issue more with the control than the collection.

Comment: This is a totally different question - more to do with Custom Control design than collections/editors.  You should delete your follow up question and post it as a new question.  SO is not a forum, so it is not set up to handle questions that chain from one sub/topic to another.

Comment: Sorry, yes that makes sense.  I'll post another question regarding this part.  Thanks again!

Comment: From the looks of it, you need to develop FlowPanel into an independent functioning control first before working it into the FLPEx.  This means a ctor that creates `N` number of buttons based on something passed, hooks up handlers, exposes clicks etc.   Your "HeaderButton" seems superfluous - it is just a local button to open/close the panel.  The menu buttons are the "trick"

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to use the chat yet, and I'll make this my last post since the original question has been solved.  While typing up my question I figured out what to do.  I created: Public Overloads Property ChildControls() in the new main panel, then on the Get returned the FlpEx controls.

Comment: No problem, I never do chat anyway.  Read my last comment: I think you need more in FlowPanel - when you create one, it seems like it needs to know menu entries etc to make other buttons.  Only when it works as desired should you involved the FlowLayoutPanel - thats is just the house for the many Panels.  You should delete your followup question because it is not an answer and will get DownVoted.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this here because I cannot do it in the comments because there is too much text and images.  Also, maybe someone coming here from a search engine will be able to get an idea of what to do.

This is what I wanted to achieve with the control:

Closed
[image]

Open
[image]

And here is the edited code to allow the (flat style) buttons to be clicked and open the parent panel.  This is a very crude method of doing it, but I put it together to check if it worked before I tied up too much time in it:

```
' collection editor will need this:
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class FlowLayoutPanelEx
    Inherits FlowLayoutPanel

    Public Sub New()

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        Padding = New Padding(0)
        BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ControlDark)
    End Sub

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
    Browsable(True),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    Bindable(True),
    Editor(GetType(FlowPanelCollectionEditor),
           GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))>
    Public Overloads Property Controls() As ControlCollection
        Get
            Return MyBase.Controls
        End Get
        Set(value As ControlCollection)

        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class HeaderButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Property BtnID As Integer
    Public Property BtnColor As System.Drawing.Color
    Public Event ButtonClicked(sender As HeaderButton, buttonID As Int32)

    Private Sub clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        RaiseEvent ButtonClicked(Me, BtnID)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class FlowPanel
    Inherits Panel
    ' ToDo: implememt IDisposable

    Private myBtn As HeaderButton

    ' allow user to specify the text for the child button 
    Public Property ButtonText As String
        Get
            If myBtn IsNot Nothing Then
                Return myBtn.Text
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            myBtn.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Margin = New Padding(0)
        Padding = New Padding(0)
        Height = 32
        BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Info)
        myBtn = New HeaderButton
        AddHandler myBtn.ButtonClicked, AddressOf Me.ItemButtonClicked

        myBtn.Height = 30
        myBtn.Margin = New Padding(0)
        myBtn.Padding = New Padding(0)
        myBtn.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        myBtn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control)
        Controls.Add(myBtn)

    End Sub

    Public Sub ItemButtonClicked(ByVal btn As HeaderButton, ByVal buttonID As Int32)

        If btn.Parent.Height = 32 Then
            btn.Parent.Height = 200
        Else : btn.Parent.Height = 32
        End If

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class FlowPanelCollectionEditor
    Inherits CollectionEditor

    Public Sub New(t As Type)
        MyBase.New(t)
    End Sub

    ' *** Magic happens here: ***
    ' override the base class to SPECIFY the Type allowed
    ' rather than letting it derive the Types from the collection type
    ' which would allow any control to be added
    Protected Overrides Function CreateNewItemTypes() As Type()
        Dim ValidTypes As Type() = {GetType(FlowPanel)}
        Return ValidTypes

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function EditValue(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                        provider As IServiceProvider,
                                        value As Object) As Object
        Return MyBase.EditValue(context, provider, value)
    End Function

End Class
```

There is so much more that I have to do, like displaying changes to the controls in the designer, implementing Idisposable, adding a collapsible button on the side, and passing the height value of the panel through the form so it will open the full height.  I'm probably going to draw the buttons to get some effects that are not available with the standard button.